# Additional to SNP (variant) calling, what is genotype calling in human genome?

Tags: genetics, terminology, variant

Variant calling in human genome aims to determine in which positions there is polymorphic site or in which positions at least one of the dna bases differs from a human reference genome. Then beside variant calling, what is genotype calling in human genome?

Maybe I am not familiar with human genome SNP calling;  I would like to know the reason behind that the process of genotype calling is **typically only** done for positions in which a SNP has already been called.

> Genotype calling is the process of determining the genotype for each individual and is typically only done for positions in which a SNP or a ‘variant’ has already been called.

Comment: Welcome to the site, please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about this site and what we do at Stack Exchange sites. Please note that one of the requirements for questions here is some evidence of research from you (the asker) in your attempt to answer the question. If you think carefully about the word "genotype" you should be able to answer this easily.

Comment: useful info:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3593722/

Comment: useful info: https://training.galaxyproject.org/training-material/topics/variant-analysis/tutorials/dip/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3593722/

**Genotype and SNP calling**:

> The process of converting base calls and quality scores into a set of
> genotypes for each individual in a sample is often divided into two
> steps: genotype calling and SNP calling. **SNP calling aims to
> determine in which positions there are polymorphisms or in which
> positions at least one of the bases differs from a reference sequence;
> the latter is also sometimes referred to as ‘variant calling’.**
> Genotype calling is the process of determining the genotype for each
> individual and is typically only done for positions in which a SNP or
> a ‘variant’ has already been called. We use the word ‘calling’ here to
> signify the estimation of one unique SNP or genotype. However, we note
> that some analyses can proceed without determining the exact identity
> of each genotype, but instead allow uncertainty regarding genotypes to
> be incorporated directly into the analyses.
>
> Genotype and SNP calling can proceed, as in early studies, by counting
> alleles at each site and using simple cutoff rules for when to call a
> SNP or genotype. More-recent methods incorporate uncertainty in a
> probabilistic framework. In the probabilistic framework, it is also
> possible to further incorporate additional information regarding
> allele frequencies and/or patterns of LD. We review these different
> approaches below, starting with the simple methods based on counting
> alleles.
>
> Early methods for calling genotypes
>
> Early NGS studies based both SNP and genotype calling on separate
> analyses of data from each individual sampled. Typically, analyses
> would first involve a filtering step in which only high-confidence
> bases would be kept. The most common cutoff used would be a Phred-type
> quality score of Q20 (QPhred = 20). **Genotype calling would then
> proceed for each individual by counting the number of times each
> allele is observed** and using fixed cutoffs.
>
> **In early NGS papers, in which only a single genome was analysed, SNP calling and genotype calling were more or less identical, as an inferred heterozygous genotype or a homozygous non-reference genotype would imply the presence of a SNP. For larger data sets containing many individuals, a SNP would be called if any individual was heterozygous or homozygous for a non-reference allele.** However, this might not be an optimal way of proceeding, because the expected false-positive rate will increase linearly with the sample size.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer. Basically this is a link only answer. It is best to answer the Q in your own words and use citations to support your argument. *Ad verbatim* copy-and-pasting large swaths of text from the internet is not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

The quote isn't a very helpful or accurate one, I'm not really sure where you got it but I can appreciate how it may be confusing.

For all intents and purposes genotype calling and variant calling are the same thing. I suppose **genotype calling** refers to the process of determining the genotype that an individual carries at a particular point in the genome (i.e. the number of copies of each particular allele that exist at that position). **Variant calling** is the process of identifying whether there exists any variation across individuals at a particular locus, which clearly you can only do once the genotypes have been called. So you can't call variants without knowing the genotypes and by calling genotypes you are kind of automatically looking for variants. So there's not really a particular distinction to be made, it's just slightly different terms that might be used in different contexts. You'd be more likely to talk about **variant calling** in the context of genotyping lots of individuals in a cohort and assessing whether any of them vary from each other or a reference sequence.

As for the quote

> ... typically only done for positions in which a SNP or a ‘variant’ has
> already been called

This is more getting at the point that genotypes are usually called at positions in the genome which are known to already vary in human populations by previous studies. Genotyping costs money and for a lot of functions, genotyping every position in the genome isn't really necessary since most of those positions don't vary at all between humans and so aren't very useful. Therefore, people figured out which positions tend to vary a lot between humans groups/individuals and just genotyped those instead of the entire genome. So instead of genotyping all ~3bn base pairs, you might genotype 500,000 which you know are likely to be variable. Nowadays, people are moving towards sequencing all base pairs in the human genome since it's more affordable to do so.

Just to add some more confusion, 'genotyping' is often used synonymously with calling genotypes on such genotyping arrays (or SNP arrays or SNP-chips as they can also be known as), whereas 'sequencing' is when you call genotypes at **every** position in the genome, not just those on an array.

In general, genomics terminology can be confusing because different people use different terms for the same thing, and the same term for different things, so it's always good to try and understand what each term means fundamentally rather than relying on the terms themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  too few community members understand the related information.